# RxJS Redux Observable Epic improvement

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have the following redux observable Epic that uses async `Auth.currentSession` from AWS Amplify seen here https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#retrieve-current-session.

So I basically have two async functions that need to be called with the actual GraphQL mutation coming second.

I am still new to RxJS and functional programming so I am wondering if this is the most efficient way to handle this. The catchError seems repetitive and the nesting seems overboard but I do like how it makes knowing which function had an issue.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions to improve this code.

```
const postEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(actionTypes.CREATE_POST),
    mergeMap(action => {
      return from(Auth.currentSession()).pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
          return from(
            client.mutate({
              mutation: gql(createPost),
              variables: {
                createPostInput: {
                  User_id: user.getIdToken().payload.id,
                  title: action.payload.title
                }
              }
            })
          ).pipe(
            map(response => createPostSuccess()),
            catchError(error => of(createPostError(error)))
          );
        }),
        catchError(error => of(createPostError(error)))
      );
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks good overall. I refector the code a bit to reduce complexity and nesting. I prefer repeating hot observable instead of nesting catch. catchError completes the observable so in your original code if it fails in the outter stream your stream will be stopped, that's probably the only issue.

```
const postEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(actionTypes.CREATE_POST),
    mergeMap(action => from(Auth.currentSession()),user=>[user,action.payload.title]),
    switchMap(([user,title]) =>client.mutate({
        mutation: gql(createPost),
        variables: {
          createPostInput: {
            User_id: user.getIdToken().payload.id,
            title
          }
        }
      })),
    map(response => createPostSuccess()),
    catchError(error => of(createPostError(error))),
    repeat()
  );
```